# SvelteKit Maintenance Mode

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

Is there a good way to do display a maintenance page when visiting any route of my SvelteKit website?

My app is hosted on Vercel, for those who want to know.

What I've tried so far:

- Set an environment variable called `MAINTENANCE_MODE` with a value `1` in Vercel.
- For development purposes I've set this in my .env file to `VITE_MAINTENANCE_MODE` and called with `import.meta.env.VITE_MAINTENANCE_MODE`.

Then inside `+layout.server.js` I have the following code to redirect to `/maintenance` route

```js
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export async function load({ url }) {
  const { pathname } = url;

  // Replace import.meta.env.VITE_MAINTENANCE_MODE with process.env.MAINTENANCE_MODE in Production
  if (import.meta.env.VITE_MAINTENANCE_MODE == 1) {
    if (pathname == "/maintenance") return;
    throw redirect(307, "/maintenance");
  } else {
    if (pathname == "/maintenance") {
      throw redirect(307, "/");
    };
  };
};
```

What I've also tried is just throwing an `error` in `+layout.server.js` with the following:

```js
import { error } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export async function load() {
  if (import.meta.env.VITE_MAINTENANCE_MODE == 1) {
    throw error(503, "Scheduled for maintenance");
  };
};
```

However this just uses SvelteKit's  static fallback error page and not `+error.svelte`. I've tried creating `src/error.html` in the hope to create a custom error page for `+layout.svelte` but couldn't get it to work.
I would like to use a custom page to display "Down for maintenance", but I don't want to create an endpoint for every route in my app to check if the `MAINTENANCE_MODE` is set to 1.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`handle` server hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle), e.g. `src/hooks.server.ts`:

```js
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    if (env.MAINTENANCE_MODE == '1' && event.route.id != '/maintenance')
        return new Response(undefined, { status: 302, headers: { location: '/maintenance' } });

    // <other logic>
    
    // Default response
    return await resolve(event);
}
```

And on the maintenance page you can prevent all further navigation:

```js
import { beforeNavigate } from '$app/navigation';

beforeNavigate(async ({ cancel }) => {
    cancel();
});
```

(Possibly add some periodic checks via `fetch` calls to navigate elsewhere once the site is back online.)

Comment: Thanx, will try this. I've wanted to do a handle hook, just couldn't figure out the redirect.
My question to this, would it also redirect if routing to eg. /login?

Comment: The code currently only excludes the `/maintenance` route (to prevent a loop), if you want to exclude others you just have to extend the `if` statement.

Comment: Nothing's happening for me during development. Would the `hooks.server.ts` only run when deployed?

Comment: No, it should always work. Make sure it is in the correct folder and check whether the default hooks location was changed via the config ([see docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks)).

Comment: Got it working. I was just due to a simple update to SvelteKit . I'll mark this as the solution

Comment: Please notice that it is now `event.route.id` instead of `event.routeId` in [Sveltekit 1.0](https://svelte.dev/blog/whats-new-in-svelte-december-2022#what-s-new-in-sveltekit)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `+layout.ts` to hook up for the maintenance mode. You can even make this conditional for some parts of the site (have frontpage still up and running).

[Here is the trick we use](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/5cb18e2e988197eb9f8413bef3aa345845297952/src/routes/trading-view/%5Bchain%5D/%2Blayout.ts):

```
import type { LayoutLoad } from './$types';
import { chainsUnderMaintenance } from '$lib/config';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load: LayoutLoad = ({ params }) => {
    // Check chain maintenance status; if under maintenance, trigger error (see +error.svelte)
    const chainName = chainsUnderMaintenance[<string>params.chain];
    if (chainName) {
        throw error(503, `Chain under maintenance: ${chainName}`);
    }
};
```